# Magento 2 orderFactory not found in vendor directory

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using Magento 2.3.4 inside a docker container for a payment gateway extension. First things first, here is the affected code:

```
<?php

namespace Magento\PGM\Block;

use Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Inbox;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction\Builder as TransactionBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\PGM\Logger\Logger;


class Main extends Template
{
    protected $_objectmanager;
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    protected $response;
    protected $config;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $transactionBuilder;
    protected $inbox;
    private $logger;
    private $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Session $checkoutSession, OrderFactory $orderFactory = null, Logger $logger, Http $response, TransactionBuilder $tb, Inbox $inbox)
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(OrderFactory::class);
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->config = $context->getScopeConfig();
        $this->transactionBuilder = $tb;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->inbox = $inbox;

        $this->urlBuilder = ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getParentId()
    {
        return $this->getData(OrderAddressInterface::PARENT_ID);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $method_data = array();
        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($this->getParentId());
        if ($order) {
            $payment = $order->getPayment();
            // The error is thrown here (" Call to a member function setTransactionId() on null")
            $payment->setTransactionId("-1");
            ...
            $payment->save();
            $order->save();

            ...
    }

    private function setApiData($order, $testmode, $instance)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Call to a member function setTransactionId() on null

I think that this is just a symptom though. The order object is not created, my IDE marks the `$order->getPayment()` method as not found at all.

The code itself should not be the problem, but the folder 'Sales\Model' does not contain an orderFactory.php file. Is the file missing or deprecated? Several modules use this file and create orders like this, for example the [Paypal PGM](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9544fb243d5848a497d4ea7b88e08609376ac39e/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Controller/Ipn/Index.php), and use the OrderFactory.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know The Factory class name is the name of Model class and append with the Factory word. So for our example, we will have TopicFactory class. You must not create this class. Magento will create it for you. Whenever Magento’s object manager encounters a class name that ends in the word ‘Factory’, it will automatically generate the Factory class in the var/generation folder if the class does not already exist. You will see the factory class in

```
ROOT/generated/code/<vendor_name>/<module_name>/Model/OrderFactory.php
```

So the first step you should go to the folder Generation to see the class is there or NOT.

If it's not there, i think you're are facing permission issue , magento cant generate (can't create file or folder) the Factory Class in Generation folder.

Comment: This seems to be the issue, I didn't check the var folder, but it is almost empty (just page_cache is there). I tried to set permissions according to the magento 2 docs, but to no avail. I will try to reinstall my magento shop and update on this issue. Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: Sorry, i gave the wrong path, the factory class in ROOT/generated/code/<vendor_name>/<module_name>/ClassFactory.php because you are in magento 2.3.4

Comment: The folder `generated/code/Magento` only contains the Framework folder, so the issue seems to be present in all of the generated code?

Comment: Yes. Because every factory classes will be generated and located under Generated/code .

Answer (score 1):

Hi orderFactory does not have payment in DB, so you cannot use this to get payment. You can try this:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Transaction\CollectionFactory; 
protected $transactions;
public function __constructor(CollectionFactory $transactions)
{
    $this->transactions = $transactions;
}
```

In your method:

```
$transactions = $this->transactions->create()->addOrderIdFilter($orderId);
...
$transactions->setTransactionId("-1");`
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, after I reinstall magento 2, I can give this a try.